# Newton Fractal writen in C

Tags: performance, c, mathematics, fractals

The code has no errors, it is just slow. It takes 1.19s to start.

How can I reduce runtime without using threads or multiple processes?

I have tried compiler optimization

```
(-o1, -o2 and -o3)
```

These did not do much.

```c
typedef struct s_float2{
    double  x;
    double  y;
}   t_float2;

static t_float2 next(t_float2 z)
{
    t_float2    new;
    double      temp_deno;

    temp_deno = 3 * (z.x * z.x + z.y * z.y) * (z.x * z.x + z.y * z.y);
    new.x = ((z.x * z.x * z.x * z.x * z.x + 2 * z.x * z.x * z.x * z.y * z.y
                - z.x * z.x + z.x * z.y * z.y * z.y * z.y + z.y * z.y)
            / temp_deno);
    new.y = ((z.y * (z.x * z.x * z.x * z.x + 2 * z.x * z.x
                    * z.y * z.y + 2 * z.x + z.y * z.y * z.y * z.y))
            / temp_deno);
    z.x -= new.x;
    z.y -= new.y;
    return (z);
}

static t_float2 find_diff(t_float2 z, t_float2 root)
{
    t_float2    new;

    new.x = z.x - root.x;
    new.y = z.y - root.y;
    return (new);
}

void    init_roots(t_float2 *roots)
{
    static unsigned int flag;

    if (!flag)
    {
        roots[0] = (t_float2){1, 0};
        roots[1] = (t_float2){-0.5, 0.866025403784438};
        roots[2] = (t_float2){-0.5, -0.866025403784438};
        flag = 1;
    }
}

unsigned int    checker_tolerance(t_fractal *fractal, t_float2 z,
    unsigned int iterations)
{
    t_float2        difference;
    static t_float2 roots[3];

    init_roots(&roots);
    difference = find_diff(z, roots[0]);
    if (fabs(difference.x) < fractal->tolerance
        && fabs(difference.y) < fractal->tolerance)
        return (1);
    difference = find_diff(z, roots[1]);
    if (fabs(difference.x) < fractal->tolerance
        && fabs(difference.y) < fractal->tolerance)
        return (1);
    difference = find_diff(z, roots[2]);
    if (fabs(difference.x) < fractal->tolerance
        && fabs(difference.y) < fractal->tolerance)
        return (1);
    return (0);
}

void    calculate_newton(t_fractal *fractal)
{
    t_float2        z;
    unsigned int    iterations;

    iterations = 0;
    z.x = (fractal->x / fractal->zoom) + fractal->offset_x;
    z.y = (fractal->y / fractal->zoom) + fractal->offset_y;
    while (iterations < fractal->max_iterations)
    {
        z = next(z);
        if (checker_tolerance(fractal, z, iterations) == 1)
            return (put_color_to_pixel(fractal, fractal->x, fractal->y,
                    fractal->color * iterations / 2));
        ++iterations;
    }
    put_color_to_pixel(fractal, fractal->x, fractal->y, 0x000000);
}
```

The github link is https://github.com/MehdiMirzaie2/fractol.

Also, if you just want the main here it is:

````c
# include <mlx.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>

typedef struct s_fractal
{
    void    *mlx;
    void    *window;
    void    *image;
    void    *pointer_to_image;
    int     bits_per_pixel;
    int     size_line;
    int     endian;
    int     x;
    int     y;
    double  zx;
    double  zy;
    double  cx;
    double  cy;
    int     color;
    double  offset_x;
    double  offset_y;
    double  zoom;
    int     name;
    int     max_iterations;
    float   tolerance;
}           t_fractal;

static void free_and_explain(t_fractal *fractal)
{
    ft_putendl_fd("Available fractals: a = mandel, b = julia, c = newton\
    \n\033[1;31mASK FOR EXTRA, check your program!\033[0m", 1);
    exit_fractal(fractal);
}

int draw_fractal(t_fractal *fractal, double cx, double cy)
{
    fractal->x = 0;
    fractal->y = 0;
    while (fractal->x < SIZE)
    {
        while (fractal->y < SIZE)
        {
            if (fractal->name == 'a')
                calculate_mandelbrot(fractal);
            else if (fractal->name == 'b')
                calculate_julia(fractal, cx, cy);
            else if (fractal->name == 'c')
                calculate_newton(fractal);
            else
                free_and_explain(fractal);
            fractal->y++;
        }
        fractal->x++;
        fractal->y = 0;
    }
    mlx_put_image_to_window(fractal->mlx, fractal->window, fractal->image, 0,
        0);
    return (0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    t_fractal   *fractal;

    if (argc != 2 || argv[1][1] != '\0')
    {
        ft_putendl_fd("Available fractals: a = mandel, b = julia, c = newton\
        \n\033[1;31mASK FOR EXTRA!\033[0m", 1);
        return (0);
    }
    fractal = malloc(sizeof(t_fractal));
    init_fractal(fractal);
    init_mlx(fractal);
    fractal->name = argv[1][0];
    mlx_key_hook(fractal->window, key_hook, fractal);
    mlx_mouse_hook(fractal->window, mouse_hook, fractal);
    mlx_hook(fractal->window, 17, 0L, exit_fractal, fractal);
    draw_fractal(fractal, -0.79, 0.15);
    mlx_loop(fractal->mlx);
    return (0);
}
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You'll receive better reviews if you show a complete example.  For example, I recommend that you [edit] to show the necessary `#include` lines, and a `main()` that shows how to call your function.  It can really help reviewers if they are able to compile and run your program.

Comment: `-o3` sets the output file name to `3`, still no optimization.  Hopefully you actually tried `-O3`.  (Also try `-O3 -march=native -ffast-math` with GCC or clang, and also `-fprofile-generate` / run it / `-fprofile-use`.  See also [Which gcc optimization flags should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36605576) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000917/how-can-i-optimize-these-loops-with-compiler-optimization-disabled) for some interesting compiler options.)

Comment: @mehdi mirzaie "It takes 1.19s to start." ---> There is no `main()`.  Post your code (with `main()` so others may attempt to compare times.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, the link to the program is [link](http://github.com/MehdiMirzaie2/fractol). Here you will find more fractals that I have implemented.

Comment: @mehdimirzaie Links too often become broken over time or code is deep is a high level link. Best to put a sample `main()` here.  No need to add difficulties for reviewers who provide quality feedback at zero cost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't like parentheses around expressions `return`ed.

I do not understand `init_roots()`. Why not just initialise `checker_tolerance()`'s `roots`, or make it a compilation unit `static const`?
(Do the numbers have a meaning? ±sqrt(¾), sin(±60°)?)

Do not repeat yourself:

```
unsigned int
checker_tolerance(t_fractal const *fractal, t_float2 z, unsigned int iterations)
{
    static const t_float2 roots[3] = {
            (t_float2){1, 0},
            (t_float2){-0.5, 0.866025403784439},
            (t_float2){-0.5, -0.866025403784439}
        };
    const int nroots = sizeof roots / sizeof *root;

    for (int root = 0 ; root < nroots ; root++) {
        t_float2 difference = find_diff(z, roots[root]);
        if (fabs(difference.x) < fractal->tolerance
            && fabs(difference.y) < fractal->tolerance)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

– still looks weird:
make `roots` a vector parameter? (Darn - C, not C++, and array/pointer & length sucks.)

In `next()`, I need to count "multiplicities" - I'd rather not:

```
static t_float2 next(t_float2 z) // const t_float2 *z?
{
    const double
        x2 = z.x * z.x, // x4 = x2 * x2, // x3 = x2 * z.x, x5 = x2 * x3,
        y2 = z.y * z.y, // y4 = y2 * y2,
        sum_of_squares = x2 + y2,
        sum_of_squares2 = sum_of_squares * sum_of_squares, // x4 + 2*x2*y2 + y4
        denominator = 3 * sum_of_squares,
        //   z.x * z.x * z.x * z.x * z.x + 2 * z.x * z.x * z.x * z.y * z.y
        // - z.x * z.x                   + z.x * z.y * z.y * z.y * z.y + z.y * z.y
        x = // (       x5 + 2 *  x3 * y2 -     x2  + z.x * y4  + y2) / denominator,
            // (z.x * (x4 + 2 *  x2 * y2 -     z.x +       y4) + y2) / denominator,
               (z.x * (sum_of_squares2 - z.x) + y2) / denominator,
        // z.y * (z.x * z.x * z.x * z.x + 2 * z.x * z.x
        //        * z.y * z.y + 2 * z.x + z.y * z.y * z.y * z.y)
        y = // (z.y * (x4 + 2 *  x2 * y2 + 2 * z.x +       y4) / denominator;
                z.y * (sum_of_squares2 + 2 * z.x) / denominator;
    z.x -= x;
    z.y -= y;
    return z;
}
```

Oh, look: I think I recognized how similar the modifications to x and y have been.

Seeing how `fractal` in `calculate_newton(t_fractal *fractal)` gets used, consider a `const t_fractal *fractal)`.
And `return ‹expression›` looks weird in a `void` function even with a `void` expression.

Comment: A pity there is no `main()` to give it a spin.

Comment: thanks for the help, here is the program link: https://github.com/MehdiMirzaie2/fractol

Comment: Interesting this code used a different constant _with no explanation_: 0.866025403784439, which is not much closer to sqrt(¾) than OP's 0.866025403784438.  0.86602540378443865 is closest `double` to sqrt(¾).

Answer (score 17):

## Use `complex` numbers

Since C99, [C supports complex numbers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex), and has many mathematical functions that work on complex numbers. I would rewrite all your code to use that. For example, for a Newton fractal with \$p(z) = z^3 - 1\$:

```
static complex double next(complex double z)
{
    complex double denominator = 3 * z * z;
    complex double numerator = z * z * z - 1;
    return z - numerator / denominator;
}
```

This will make your code look much nicer. It may or may not be more performant, but that brings me to:

## Use `-ffast-math` and `-march=native`

While in pure mathematics, multiplication of real and complex numbers is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), it's not for floating point numbers stored in computers. The reason is that after every operation, the calculated number is rounded back to the precision of a `float` or `double`. The order of operations therefore matters for the final result. Compilers won't reorder those operations by default. However, if you use the `-ffast-math` compiler flag (or `/fp:fast` for MSVC), then it will be able to reorder operations, even if it might change the precision of the result.

By default, compilers also compile binaries that are guaranteed to run on a wide range of processors; for example if you compile for the amd64 architecture, it will run on all amd64 machines, even old ones. If you have a newer CPU however, it might have some extra instructions that could have sped up your calculation, but would break backwards compatibility with older CPUs. If you use the `-march=native` compiler flag, then it will use newer instructions if possible.

Comment: Aside: `z * z * z - 1` in not as numerically stable as `(z*z + z + 1)*(z - 1)`, especially for `z` near 1.0`.

Comment: Hmmm, Need to apply [the idea](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285956/newton-fractal-writen-in-c#comment569175_285958) further: `(z*z + z + 1)*(z - 1)` --> `(z*(z + 1) + 1)*(z - 1)` to also improve `z` near -1.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I would be more worried about the denominator than the numerator. How are you going to make the term \$-1 / 3 z^2\$ in the result stable near \$z = 0\$?

Comment: G. Sliepen The above suggestions help the _precision_  for values of `z` near 1.0 and -1.0.   Near `z == 0`, code relies on the _exponential range_ of the floating point type and is not a stability problem, but an overflow one.  Near `z== 0`, `next()` is stable, even if it approaches infinity.

Answer (score 5):

**Suspected subtle bug**

Try

```
  printf("%a\n", 0.866025403784438);
  printf("%a\n", sqrt(3)/2);
  printf("%a\n", 0.86602540378443865);
  printf("%a\n", 0.86602540378443864676372317075294);
  printf("%a\n", nextafter(sqrt(3)/2,0));
```

My output

```
0x1.bb67ae8584ca5p-1  // 5 ULP away from the best root3/2
0x1.bb67ae8584caap-1
0x1.bb67ae8584caap-1
0x1.bb67ae8584caap-1
0x1.bb67ae8584ca9p-1
```

Rather than code a less than precise value, use enough significant decimal digits to form the best floating point value.
For `double`, use `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` **or more** significant digits.
`DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is commonly 17.

```
typedef struct s_float2{
    double  x;
    double  y;
}   t_float2;

// (t_float2){-0.5, 0.866025403784438};
//                 12345678901234567
(t_float2){-0.5, 0.86602540378443865};
```

---

OTOH, perhaps OP wanted to start further away than closest `double` to `sqrt(3)/2`?